# Log error return after an API call for login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Currently I am using an API to verify credentials and connect. When the credentials are correct, no problem, the user can log in. But when the identifiers are incorrect, it is impossible to retrieve an error code to be able to display a popup with a message.

```
async login(username: string,  password: string) {
    (await this.api.postRequest( this.env.APIlogin, { username: username, password: password })).subscribe(async (res: any) => {
        return this.storage.setItem(TOKEN, res.token).then(() => {
            this.getUser(res);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.env.HomePage);
        });
    },
    err => {
        console.log('Error :' + err);
    });
}
```

For example there I should have a return in my console of the error, only that does not return anything. If I use the Android debug, however, I have an error return which appears but no log.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by checking after the API call if the token is empty.
This then allowed me to display a popup without going through the return of errors from the API.

```
if(res?.refresh_token != null) {
    // Code
} else {
    this.popup();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error in Javascript: `TypeError: Cannot read property ‘refresh_token’ of undefined.`

Thanks to **Optional Chaining**, you can just insert a `?` between the property name and the period between the next property.
With that, it will just return `undefined` instead of throwing that error.

Example: `refresh_token?.something`

Comment: The refresh_token arrives after the API call, is it a bit normal that it displays an error? I think you did not understand the problem exposed.

Comment: Yes, it is normal to display that kind of error (refresh_token is undefined or null after API call). Check out refresh_token in your implementation and add the optional chaining.

Comment: It allows to remove the error from the token but that's not what I want. But I want to be able to display the error returned by the API : err => {
        console.log('Error :' + err);
    }